# tymondesigns/jwt-auth return user_not_found

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, laravel-5.4

I am implementing tymondesigns/jwt-auth first time in my project.
I am success to generate token. But having problem to get authenticated user. It returns user_not_found error.

Here give my code snippet step by step

**Token Generation Code:**

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::where('username', $request->username)->where('password', md5($request->password))->first();
        if(empty($user)){
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
        try{
            $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
```

**Get Authenticated User Code:**

I passed `token` in query string.

```
public function getAuthenticatedUser()
{

    try {

        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {

            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }

    } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

    }

    // the token is valid and we have found the user via the sub claim
    return response()->json(compact('user'));
}
```

This Code return this result `["user_not_found"]`

**Some Important Notes**

My `users` tables primary key is `user_id` That's why I change 2 files

- In `User` Model added `protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';`
- In `config/jwt.php` File change `'identifier' => 'user_id'`

**I also do some debugging. Here I share this**
I print the query log and find this query log

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `users` where `users`.`user_id` is null limit 1"//user_id is null. I think here is the problem
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 3.94
  ]
]
```